# Query from a database that might have multiple values for a field

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

We have an excel sheet formatted something like this:

```
APP_ID    FirstName   LastName    Experience         GPA 
======================================================
12        XXX1        YYY1        Lifeguard          3.4
12                                Soccer Referee     3.9
13        XXX2        YYY2        Server; Hostess    3.2
13                                Chemistry Tutor
13                                Teaching Assistant
```

As you can see, for experience and GPA, we might have multiple values. I am going to design a form so that they can query and search for an experienced person or people with some minimum GPA. (Each person might have multiple GPA, we only consider the maximum)

I want to them to able to just copy and paste these data into access and use my form. (They have minimum knowledge of access).
So, when I import it to access I get something like this:

```
ID     APP_ID    FirstName   LastName    Experience         GPA 
================================================================
1      12        XXX1        YYY1        Lifeguard          3.4
2      12                                Soccer Referee     3.9
3      13        XXX2        YYY2        Server; Hostess    3.2
4      13                                Chemistry Tutor
5      13                                Teaching Assistant
```

How can I do these searches in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your table was called Table3, you would write a query like this:

```
select * from table3
inner join (
  select firstname, lastname, max(gpa) as maxgpa
  from Table3
  group by firstname, lastname
) temptable
on table3.firstname = temptable.firstname
and table3.lastname = temptable.lastname
and table3.gpa = temptable.maxgpa
```

to get records with highest GPA for each person.

If your table looks like this:

```
ID  APP_ID  FirstName   LastName    Experience      GPA
1   12      John        Smith       Lifeguard       3.4
2   12      John        Smith       Soccer Referee  3.9
3   13      Matt        Rogers      Server          3.2
4   13      Matt        Rogers      Tutor           3.4
5   13      Matt        Rogers      TA              3.5
```

The result will be:

```
ID  APP_ID  FirstName   LastName    Experience      GPA
2   12      John        Smith       Soccer Referee  3.9
5   13      Matt        Rogers      TA              3.5
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How can I query the experiences? For example if I want to find "Soccer Referee", the record doesn't have informations like first name and last name. Or can I populate first name and last to empty records?

Comment: In a database setting, always attempt to fill all information, or as much as possible. Populating name to empty records will work best.